# boostrap-vue table action on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table in Vue.js having data and I would like to add some "action click" into the last cell.

[About boostrap-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-table)

This is my table template:

```
<BootstrapTable :columns="table.columns" :data="table.data" :options="table.options"  v-if="table.ready">
```

And the data:

```
this.table = {
   ready: false,
   columns: [
               {
                field: 'id',
                title: 'id',
                visible: true
               },
                {
                field: 'test',
                title: 'test',
                visible: true,
                formatter: addClicks(this)
               },
               ...
  ]}
```

[**edit**]

I would like something like this but, obviously, this is not rendered:

```
...
formatter: function (value, row) {
   const ve = "<span @click='setElement("+row.id+")' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Set</span>";
   return ve;
}
```

How should I do that to have my action on click?

Comment: The `clickcell` event has the row and the field name that you can match with the row inded and the column index respectively (https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#onclickcell). Maybe you could use that to detect if the clicked cell is the last one.

Comment: thanks this could work, but I prefer an action in vue style just like the edit I add in my post.

Comment: You can register the event in "vue style". Simply register the action in your BootstrapTable element with `@clickcell="yourHandler`. Manually creating element is anti-pattern with Vue, as you are not exploiting the template.

Comment: Yes, true. This is a temporary solution. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger OnClickCell event from bootstrap-vue table

Evebt: onClickCell
jQuery Event: click-cell.bs.table

Parameter: field, value, row, $element

Detail:

Fires when user click a cell, the parameters contain:

field: the field name corresponding to the clicked cell.
value: the data value corresponding to the clicked cell.
row: the record corresponding to the clicked row.
$element: the td element.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use @onClickCell="cellclick"at moment.